# How can I set width of empty HTML table columns automatically when the column header is vertical?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to lay out a table in HTML where:

1. The column headings have vertical text
2. Some of the columns (in the body) are empty

and ideally I want the browser to calculate all the column widths itself.

What I see is that non empty columns are fine but the empty columns are squashed up as if the browser has not accounted for the width of the rotated text.

HTML here (note column 'two' is empty)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><div class="vertical">One</div></th>
      <th><div class="vertical">Two</div></th>
      <th><div class="vertical">Three</div></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td></td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td></td><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and CSS (also tried with `-webkit-writing-mode`, same result):

```
.vertical { writing-mode: vertical-lr}
```

There are some other questions here with vertical column heads but they aren't asking about empty columns and mostly using `transform: rotate(-90.0deg)` which looks ugly to me.

Illustrated here (upper table showing the problem - I made the lower table with horizontal headings to show that the browser *can* calculate the widths properly):

[image: Rendered table]

and in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j5srL1m7/

I see the same on Firefox 74 and Safari, so I guess it's something in the CSS layout spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `min-width`, so the browser can still adjust to wider content.

```
th,
td {
  min-width: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Certainly works in my case! I can see it wouldn't work though, if the font was taller than its em width, or if the header went onto two lines

Comment: By the way, NinaW, are you using Chrome? If so, do you see the same effect?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and in your demo it looks as it should without adding `min-width`. `writing-mode` not well supported on older browsers https://caniuse.com/#search=writing-mode